# export a javascript instance of a class to another file and retain prototype and methods

Tags: javascript, class, methods, import, export

I am working on becoming better at javascript, node, and express and am trying to serve up an instance of a class from an app.js file to another js file and still be able to retain and implement the class methods. I am using node.js and express. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

person.js

```
export default class Person{
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    someMethod(){
        this.name = "new name";
    }
}
```

app.js

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import Person from "./public/classes.js";
 
const myPerson = new Person("John Smith");

//setup Express server here
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listenings on port ${port}`);
});

//provide route to fetch object from
app.get("/getPerson", (req, res) => {
  res.send(myPerson);
});
```

otherFile.js

```
import Person from "./classes.js";

//fetch the Person object from the app.js
const response = await fetch("/getPerson");
const myPerson = await response.json();

//Try to call a method from the Person class on myPerson
myPerson.someMethod() // this throws an Uncaught TypeError: myPerson.someMethod() is not a function
```

It is this last line that I am trying to fix. I would like to be able to call the methods of the class on the myPerson object. Upon examination it appears the myPerson object no longer has the methods in its prototype that were originally attached by the class. What am I doing wrong and is there a better way to do this?

### UPDATE:

---

After some experimentation, I found two ways to use the Person methods on the fetched object.

1. Use .setProtoTypeOf() method on myPerson as follows:

```
myPerson.setProtoTypeOf(Person);
```

2. Create a method that will convert the json response into a new Person obj.

```
const person = new Person(myPerson.name);
```

Of course this would be more complicated depending upon the number of fields in the passed object, but since MDN gives a HUGE warning when using .setProtoTypeOf(), I think this is the better way.

Comment: JSON doesn't support serializing classes, everything is turned into a plain object. You need a method in the class to create a Person instance from an object.

Comment: Remember that the point of JSON is to be language-independent. It can't serialize methods, class hierarchy, etc.

Comment: Can you better define your actual goal? It seems like you're describing the idea you had to solve a problem, not the problem itself.

Comment: - Barmar Thanks! That makes a lot of sense! I am admittedly a noobie at this, and I wasn't even thinking about the language-independent aspect. I was just trying to find the easiest way to essentially "pass" an array of class instance objects from the app.js file to another file where I could then do some work on them using the methods within the class. I also tried to do an export and import but could not get it to work. I will create a method that will create new Person instances based upon the json response.